# Should academics be concerned about professorwatchlist.org

Tags: united-states, social-media, academic-freedom

There is a relatively new website: http://professorwatchlist.org/ whose [mission](http://professorwatchlist.org/index.php/about-us):

> is to expose and document college professors who discriminate against conservative students and advance leftist propaganda in the classroom.
>
> Help us identify, and expose more professors who have demonstrated liberal bias in the classroom.

What are the likely consequences for a US academic that is *exposed* as having a liberal bias in the classroom?

Comment: (This is not an answer, just additional information that I felt were relevant when looking at this website) It appears to be aggregating articles from online newspapers, not anonymous reports. Presumably, it also means that the professor must have taken action based on his "radical views", enough that it makes the news. And "leftist propaganda" seems to be a dubious shortcut : some of the professors here are (presumed) holocaust deniers or supporting terrorism, for example...

Comment: A significant proportion of the articles reference a source on campusreform.org, which I believe could be another example of websites for this question.

Comment: In my opinion the likely consequences are nil -- but I don't believe anyone can be sure.

Comment: Liberal bias meaning supporting the scientific consensus on evolutionary theory, anthropogenic climate change, etc.?

Comment: While its heart is to my taste on the wrong side of its chest, I don't see anything truly harmful or worrisome about this site.  On the contrary, if I were the kind of academic who felt strongly enough about my political views to promote them in the classroom and/or on social media, I might perhaps enjoy the PR.  One of the professors whose color photo is on the main page, is described as "an admitted socialist." The horror, the horror!

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, there are 'conservative' professors out there getting raked through the coals too.

Comment: @Hobbes it doesn't. Is there a conservative watch list also? I am happy for my question to be less biased.

Comment: Nothing like this, it's mostly just a case-by-case scenario.  I was thinking of this specifically: http://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-37875695

Comment: Is this an ad for the website or something? I have trouble imagining it's well-known or that its use is widespread. (I'm not a professor but if I got reported on a website like that I would probably feel honored)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi not an ad. It is all over my social media feed, covered by the NYT and BBC, and written about by InsideHigherEd. I, potentially erroneously, thought it was a well known thing. The concept of being on a watch list is a little disturbing to me. The closest thing I can think of is the PETA lists.

Comment: The list is fairly short and each of the professors I clicked on already have a Wikipedia page talking about their beliefs, so this doesn't seem problematic at all to me. They also all seem to be quite extreme so most profs won't need to worry unless you're building bombs or brainwashing children.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, It's popping up on blogs, twitter, and news sites.  I guess I don't see it as dangerous, or particularly useful, since it is a private website.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If that website is really about what it says it's about, then I don't think there's anything to worry about. Academics should be open to criticism, especially if they are vocal about their political opinions. Academic freedom means the government should not interfere with what professors teach, not that they should be shielded from criticism. There certainly is political bias among university professors and it's not unhealthy *per se* to question that via independent media.

Off course, this website is very partial and lumps together extremists, people under FBI scrutiny or who were convicted with people with simply non-conservative opinions, and people whose research actually contradicts some of the American conservative positions. That last bit is probably the only worrisome aspect.

I suspect readers of that website are really looking for a confirmation of opinions they already have. I don't think it's going to have a lot of traffic from random people (apart from the one you're generating with that link). That is also true of blogs and website from the other side of the political spectrum.

If such websites challenge facts because they conflict with their political opinions, then there is a threat and it's our job to fight it with science, not with political activism.

Comment: In terms of "traffic" it has inspired a bunch of [twitter posts](https://twitter.com/hashtag/trollprofwatchlist?f=tweets&vertical=default&src=hash) and a couple of articles/posts on inside higher ed.

Answer (score 4):

I very much doubt we need to be concerned with it *at this point*.

Collections like this have existed for a long time. When I was an undergrad, a minor incident on campus got spun up into Clear Evidence of Oppression (tm) and gets trotted out now, more than a decade and a half later. The site is, at the moment, pretty poorly designed, primarily a collection of innuendo and "X professor was mean to me", and like many user-submission dependent sites, is currently somewhat inundated with obviously fake examples.

Beyond that, the very pretense of the site, that there's a clear bias in favor of professors pushing liberal ideas that pervades and dominates academia also implies that exposure of a professor doing just that...won't do much, because an academics career is primarily dictated by other academics.

The list is only a threat given moves to shift the evaluation of academics into the political sphere. But those are separate actions, that should (or should not) be opposed on their own merit, because they have implications far beyond a random PAC's website.

Comment: Could you give an example of an "obviously fake example"? Does it carry a source, and if yes, is the source spreading obviously wrong information?

Comment: @T.Verron They appear to be trying to clean them up, but at one point fairly recently both Professor Dumbledore and Professor Henry "Indiana" Jones Jr. were on there.

Comment: @T.Verron There are others, such as the UNC Asheville reports: http://professorwatchlist.org/index.php/watch-list-directory/search-by-school/106-university-of-north-carolina-asheville that, given the source's track record I would be *extremely* skeptical of.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is obviously backlash from the University professors who have been publicly named-and-shamed over the past 4 months for holding conservative views. Jordan Peterson and  Michael Rectenwald are the first that spring to mind, however there have been others.

Frankly, I don't think it will have the same effect and there's nothing to worry about. In all the examples of conservatives losing their jobs for speaking out against liberal views publicly (or privately and getting dox'd), the Dean of the institution or some other power figure within the university was the one to make it official and actually punish the conservative professor. Get them fired, academic leave, open letters, etc. The reverse just doesn't seem anywhere near as likely - an overtly conservative dean punishing a liberal professor? You'd have more chance of finding a unicorn. What i'm getting at is that liberal privilege exists within universities, and conservatives, ironically, don't have much sway over things. Liberal professors really don't need to be worried - but i'd still say that for the next 1 or 2 years i'd try and check as much of your own political baggage, whatever it may be, at the classroom door.